# Drag and drop function using cypress is not working

Tags: drag-and-drop, cypress

[Drag and drop plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AScoA.png)

```
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="category-items ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ng-star-inserted" rpnodedraggable="" type="gateway" pid="68ee0524-70fa-5308-8450-4cbe585c4e5a" consumertype="Pull" name="HTTP">
    <img _ngcontent-c4="" alt="..." src="https://demoqa.blob.core.windows.net/reekoh/plugin-icon/86d81dab-41eb-5c24-a5c5-b2158d9ae677.png" /> HTTP Gateway
    <!---->
    <i _ngcontent-c4="" aria-hidden="true" class="fal fa-fw text-muted helper fa-thumbtack ng-star-inserted" role="button" title="Unpin this plugin"></i>
</div>
```

I'm using the code below seems is not working

```
cy.get(":nth-child(3) > :nth-child(2) > .category-items")
  .trigger("dragstart", { force: true }, { dataTransfer });
cy.get(".workspace-overlay-new.ng-star-inserted")
  .trigger("drop", { dataTransfer })
  .wait(5000);
```